# How do I configure Shibboleth v3 IdP for WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, shibboleth, wso2-identity-server

I am attempting to configure our WSO2 Identity Server (5.1.0) to talk to our Shibboleth Identity Provider v3 (3.2.1) server.

When I attempt to authenticate, I get an error in my Shibboleth IdP logs which suggests to me that my metadata for the WSO2 server is wrong:

```
2016-06-30 15:24:48,564 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.AbstractMetadataResolver:334] - Metadata backing store does not contain any EntityDescriptors with the ID: MYENTITYID
2016-06-30 15:24:48,564 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.BasicRoleDescriptorResolver:198] - Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity MYENTITYID
2016-06-30 15:24:48,564 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.BasicRoleDescriptorResolver:281] - Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity MYENTITYID
2016-06-30 15:24:48,564 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.BasicRoleDescriptorResolver:252] - Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity MYENTITYID
```

I'm following documentation from the WSO2 site here:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/How+To%3A+Configure+Shibboleth+IdP+as+a+Trusted+Identity+Provider

I have the Shib IdP v3 working with other services, but a very new to that version and don't generally dig deep into Shibboleth anyway beyond setting up attribute resolution and release for relying parties.

Could someone with more experience in either the Shibboleth IdP arena or the WSO2 Identity Server arena point me in the direction of resolving this or at least narrowing down whether it's a general IdP configuration issue or a WSO2 metadata issue ?

Comment: the doc seems to be having some issues(a bit outdated), WSO2 is looking into this and will get back to you soon.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation from WSO2 site is based on Shib IdP v2.
You can still use it on v3, but you would need to enable v2 compatibility
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/NameIDGenerationConfiguration

There is no need though, the steps for v3 are quite similar.

1. AFAI can tell, Shibboleth does not support the unspecified name id format. It could be possible to tweak it to support it, but I have not found issues letting Shibboleth use the transient format. Likewise, I see reason to not use a persistent name id either. Thus, there is no need to modify the name id configuration.
2. The AttributeFilterPolicy is now defined on file /conf/attribute-filter.xml (or the attribute filter file loaded by /conf/services.xml). This policy specifies which attributes can be disclosed to each SP, so you need one entry for each of your SPs.
3. Since IS does not support metadata files yet, you need to tailor one and save it at /metadata/wso2is.xml The one in the WSO2 Site is a good start. Just keep in mind that the NameID Format does nothing if it requires the unspecified format, and that you might want to pass additional attributes in the SPSSODescriptor, in my case I had to add the following: `AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true"`. I also added the signing and encrypting x509 certificates that WSO2IS will use when sending requests to Shibboleth.
4. Next, you need to tell Shibboleth that you want to use that metadata file by adding something like the following to file /conf/metadata-providers.xml 
   `<MetadataProvider id="wso2is"
       xsi:type="FilesystemMetadataProvider"
       metadataFile="%{idp.home}/metadata/wso2is.xml">
   </MetadataProvider>`
5. Now, when you configure the IdP on WSO2IS, you need to map the claims/attributes that Shibboleth shares with WSO2IS (as defined in Shibboleth by /conf/attribute-filter.xml) to the WSO2 IS dialect. To do that, you go to your IdP configuration, expand Claim Configuration, then expand Basic Claim Configuration, there you can add as many claim mappings as you need.[This is an example of the Claims Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P1Yb.jpg)

I hope this helps.